# why knapsack problem is a NP complete?

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, knapsack-problems

I understand that knapsack problem is solved with dynamic programming in O(nW) time which is not polynomial but there is a greedy solution for knapsack problem which solves it with O(nLgn) time so how is it that there exists an algorithm with polynomial time for knap sack but it is still considered a npComplete?

Comment: "but there is a greedy solution for knapsack problem which solves it with O(nLgn) time", what solution?

Comment: @xskxzr here:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fractional-knapsack-problem/

Comment: fractional knapsack is not knapsack

Comment: @ratchetfreak but we can solve the 0-1 problem with this algorithm too

Comment: @Moeinh77 The "else" part in the greedy algo i.e the part that breaks the item into fraction is the one responsible for the greedy approach. You cannot break item in 0-1 problem i.e no support for the greedy approach.

Comment: @Ankur so simply we will act like 0-1 in else part and wont take the thing thats heavier than remaining space

Comment: @Moeinh77 But that won't produce the optimal solution in most cases.